# Split function in hive not working

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a column with name `Date_of_Birth` where date is in format `1978-07-23`.

I am trying this code for splitting, but its not working.

```
SELECT 
  case when split(Date_of_Birth,'\\-')[2] < 1900 
  THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00'  
  else cast(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date_of_Birth, 'M/d/yyyy')) as string) end as DOB 
from rd_hr.wd_employees_history
```

Comment: shouldn't it be [0]?

Comment: Down-voted + voted to close **(1)** The data sample and the code refer to 3(!) different formats. **(2)** "not working"? **(3)** You could have debug it yourself in seconds by selecting the expressions that construct the CASE statement. **P.s.** **(1)** You are working with strings where DATE and TIMESTAMP types are supported **(2)** It seems pointless to convert dates to timestamps

Answer (score 0):

After converting the date to `YYYY/MM/DD`, you take the greatest value between '1900-01-01' and Date_of_Birth:

```
SELECT 
    greatest(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date_of_Birth, 'MM/dd/yyyy')), '1900-01-01 00:00:00') AS DOB 
FROM rd_hr.wd_employees_history
```

Casting the date as it is will return `NULL`, see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps